# Send Activity Notification in MS Teams for the personal application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created one personal app which is added as in the Microsoft teams. Now I have a requirement to Send Activity Notification in Activity Feed for the users who match certain criteria.

My question is related to the Send Notification Graph API.

When I try to add the activities in my manifest.json file it is not displayed in the App studio. That section disappeared.

When I try to run the Graph API command it fails.

Can someone guide me with step by step implementation for the custom app?

**Error I get when try in Graph Explorer**

**The value of the topic must match the graph resource path.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activity feed notification APIs in Microsoft Graph to extend this functionality to your apps.
Requirements for using the activity feed notification APIs:

- The Teams app manifest must have the Azure AD app ID added to the
  webApplicationInfo section.(Teams app manifest version must be 1.7 or greater)
- Activity types must be declared in the activities section in manifest schema.
- The Teams app must be installed for the    recipient, either
  personally, or in a team or chat they are part of.

For detailed steps ,please follow below doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#understanding-the-basics-of-activity-feed-notification

Comment: Thanks Prasad, I have manifest version 1.11
-Activity Type is defined in the manifest.json
- When I upload a zip using App Studio, it removes the activities section from the maniefest file. 
- I have also tried with the custom app installation option. Still same behaviour I get

Comment: Why My Activities section is removed each time I upload the app?

Comment: Could you please try to upload using [Dev portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/teams-developer-portal) and check if it helps.

Comment: Hello Prasad, is there a possibility to have a web job which can send activity feed notification to the user?>

Comment: Not sure about the same